# Failed to execute goal org.springframework

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

My Maven project flag ERROR: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE:repackage (repackage) on project pet-clinic-data: Execution repackage of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.1.3.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class

This is my dependency

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>sfg-pet-clinic</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>pet-clinic-web</artifactId>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>pet-clinic-data</artifactId>
        <groupId>guru.springframework</groupId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :pet-clinic-data

Comment: i know you asked this a long time ago, but do you recall how you solved this, currently facing the same problem

Comment: I am experiencing this on a sporadic basis. Simply running `mvn clean` from the terminal/command prompt clears it up - for a time. It's a recurring issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Maybe try adding compiler and mapstruct plugins for build. Just a hunch though, I'm still beginner.